# Expo Apple Pay Stripe Merchant Identifier Issue

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Apple Pay on my Expo managed app.

I followed the documentation here `https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay` except adding the capability in XCode (because it's an Expo app and it doesn't use Expo).

I have included my merchant ID in the `plugins` folder in my `app.json`.

And I have also wrapped my whole app in the `<StripeProvider />` and included the merchantIdentifier there.

```
    <StripeProvider merchantIdentifier="merchant.xxx.xxx.xxx" >
          <App />
        </StripeProvider>
    enter code here
```

I believe that I've followed the documentation laid out by Expo and Stripe.

If I run `expo config --type introspect` I can see the entitlement there:

```
     ios: {
        entitlements: {
          'aps-environment': 'development',
          'com.apple.developer.in-app-payments': [
            'merchant.com.xxx.xxx'
          ]
        },
```

I then run `eas build -p ios` and create an `ipa` file. I then upload that to TestFlight to give the functionality a test on a real device.

But as soon as I try to call `presentApplePay()`, I get the error `You must provide merchantIdentifier`.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `expo-payments-stripe` or `@stripe/stripe-react-native library`?
Did you include the `publishableKey` in your [StripeProvider](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=react-native#set-merchantid)?

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the publishableKey as well.